# Reading maven command line args

Tags: maven-2, maven

I want to take a build number passed as an argument when running maven and inject it into some HTML files.

To give an example:
Build command would be "mvn -DBUILdNUM=1"

I would like to take this and inject it into an html file (in a comment hopefully) replacing something like ${builnum}.

I would also like to use something similar for cache busting my js scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Maven Resource Filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) for this.